# Linked Questions across different StackExchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

I was thinking about a whole family of grey questions that the SE structure kind of makes difficult to answer. If there are problems which overlap with two areas, say Physics and one of the Engineering sites, and require expertise in both fields, should there be a mechanism to create a multi-forum question. Questions like these may not be suitable to just migrate over but still contribute to the Physics discussion.

For example here is a question I asked:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/ricci-tensor-calculus-and-matrix-calculus

It's as relevant to physics as it is to engineering and math. That being said it would be difficult to get a satisfying question unless you have people from the math and engineering area who also prowl the Physics forum. It's on topic and a satisfying answer would help refine an understanding of Physics vs. Engineering.

I was thinking it would be interesting to see different SE forums being able to host the same question with the responses from all the forums it is in.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I've brought this up once on the mother meta, but of course we can rediscuss it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration

Comment: I think the kind of questions that would qualify for this are rare, but for those few this seems like a valid idea. One problem is who decides what sites to multi-post on? I wouldn't trust the OP because too many will multi-post frivolously. Maybe this is something that has to be asked for via a flag, but that might make a lot of busywork for mods dealing with many inappropriate requests.